# How do I create an AJAX filter for a view?

Tags: 7, taxonomy-terms, views

I have created a page using Views and it works fine. I want to add an AJAX filter to this page to allow visitors to filter the contents based on PubDate or by Taxonomy/Vocabulary for this content type. How can I accomplish this?

Comment: Hello Lina, and welcome to _Drupal Answers_. For which Drupal version is your question?

Comment: it is for drupal 6.19

Answer (score 10, accepted):

1. Edit the view, and add a filter to the page:

   - **Drupal 6:** Third column, section is called *Filters*
   - **Drupal 7:** First column, section is called *Filter Criteria*
2. When you configure the filter, you want to expose it:

   - **Drupal 6:** Click the *Expose* button in the top right of the configure area
   - **Drupal 7:** Check *Expose this filter to visitors, to allow them to change it*
3. Enable AJAX:

   - **Drupal 6:** *Use AJAX* is under *Basic settings* in the first column
   - **Drupal 7:** *Use AJAX* is under *Advanced* → *Other* in the third column

When the view is saved, there will now be a form that'll allow users to filter the view dynamically via AJAX.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe, you can use the Better exposed filters module to change output of your filter items to links.

And Use AJAX option in Advanced settings of a view to make filtering ajaxifyed.

http://drupal.org/project/better_exposed_filters